# Google Play Console Jquery Security jquery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I raised the application on Google Play, this problem appeared

> Security alert
>
> Your app contains one or more libraries with known security issues. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.
>
> Vulnerable JavaScript libraries:

```text
Name    Version Known issues            Identified files
jquery  3.3.1   SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006   res/raw/jquery.js
Affects APK version 7.
```

Can someone advise me of a solution to the problem with easy steps, preferably to attach photos?
Thanks...!

Comment: jQuery is pretty good about backwards compatibility. Just upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Thank you very much ... but how  upgrade to the latest version..?

Comment: How is jQuery used in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to a newer version of jQuery!

Comment: Thank you very much ... but how upgrade to the latest version..?